# Communication between workers in uwsgi

Tags: python, django, multithreading, ipc, uwsgi

I'm relatively new to Python, coming from a .Net background.

The short version: How can I create an application-wide singleton or some other mechanism to allow multiple threads/processes to communicate with each other?

Maybe I'm spoilt but in .Net, I'd just create something in `App_Start` or something else at the "application level". How can I do the same in python/uwsgi?

The long version:

We've got a restful API written using Django.

Some of the calls require some pre-processing and then passing to a back-end system which performs long-running operations.

The flow at the moment looks something like...

- Receive request to process all documents matching given criteria
- Api determines which documents match those criteria (on the order of 100,000 - takes 15-20s)
- Api generates a uuid for this batch request
- Api publishes a message to a back-end queue for each of those documents, referencing the batch id.
- Api listens on a different queue for "completed" messages and counts success/failures for each batch id (~1-15 minutes)
- While processing is happening, UI can request an update for a specific batch id

We need to listen to the response queue using a different thread to that which is used to serve pages since it's in a [wait spin-loop](http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/distributed-messaging-using-rabbitmq-and-python/)...

```
while True:
    self.channel.wait()
```

I was handling this by getting a reference to a `QueueManager` which is a singleton. The manager fires off the initial request, records the batch id and then, in a second thread, monitors the queue and updates local state.

We don't actually care about preserving the state long-term - If the messages are on the queue, the processing will be done by the back-end and the state monitoring is only a cue to the user that things are underway. If they browse away, they also lose access to the status (batch id is stored in-memory in  JS)

This had a couple of benefits - we avoided using a database for syncing information (and the associated cleanup). We were able to use a single thread as a message consumer and didn't have to worry about concurrency issues as only one thread will ever collect messages/update the local state.

So... Now it's time to run it using uwsgi I've found a major issue. If I set the number of processes to 1, the the singleton works as expected, but all requests are blocked during the 15-20s that the api is processing data. Clearly that's unacceptable. Conversely, if I spin up multiple workers, each has its own singleton and its own message listener - so it's pretty much random if the publisher and consumer are the same process. And even if they are, the request for a status update probably won't end up at that same process.

How can I swap state information between multiple workers? Is there a way to use multiple threads instead of multiple workers?

It seems like I really need:

- n threads, each serving requests
- 1 thread listening on the queue
- some in-memory way of communicating between them

Note I've already got `--enable-threads` but that only seems to apply to new threads I spawn (no idea why that wouldn't be enabled by default)

Comment: Was a solution ever found to this?

Comment: @Will Unfortunately not and the documentation is abysmal. There seems to be a uwsgi management process that can relaunch uwsgi processes as required. We wanted 1 process multiple threads instead of multiple processes with 1 thread. In any case, we ended up leavbing uwsgi so I never solved the problem. Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

To spawn multiple threads just add --threads N where N is the number of threads to spawn.

Pay attention, it will works only if you have a single worker/process. Another common approach is using the uWSGI caching framework (the name is misleading, infact is a shared dictionary). It will allows you to share data between workers and threads.