# uWSGI: working with multiple clients through websockets

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, uwsgi

I'm new to uWSGI and I'm working on a web application that would require a lot of web-socket communication. I decided to practice by creating a simple chat application.

From [uWSGI docs](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/WebSockets.html):

```
def application(env, start_response):
    # complete the handshake
    uwsgi.websocket_handshake(env['HTTP_SEC_WEBSOCKET_KEY'], env.get('HTTP_ORIGIN', ''))
    while True:
        msg = uwsgi.websocket_recv()
        uwsgi.websocket_send(msg)
```

I don't want to use this approach because

1. You can send a message to your client only after he sent you something;
2. You don't have access to other websocket connections, so basically you only communicate with 1 client.

However the same page has an [example](https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/blob/master/tests/websockets_chat_async.py) of how to implement a chat. It would be great but they use Redis in their example:

```
    r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
    channel = r.pubsub()
    channel.subscribe('foobar')

    websocket_fd = uwsgi.connection_fd()
    redis_fd = channel.connection._sock.fileno()

    while True:
        uwsgi.wait_fd_read(websocket_fd, 3)
        uwsgi.wait_fd_read(redis_fd)
        uwsgi.suspend()
```

From what I see, Redis here is used as an external server that allows different uWSGI request handlers use the same data.

Does this really need to be that difficult?

Take a look at the chat solution using Node.js (example taken from javascript.ru):

```
var WebSocketServer = new require('ws');

// connected clients
var clients = {};

// WebSocket-server serves 8081 port
var webSocketServer = new WebSocketServer.Server({
  port: 8081
});
webSocketServer.on('connection', function(ws) {

  var id = Math.random();
  clients[id] = ws;
  console.log("new connection " + id);

  ws.on('message', function(message) {
    console.log("recieved a new message: " + message);

    for (var key in clients) {
      clients[key].send(message);
    }
  });

  ws.on('close', function() {
    console.log("connection closed " + id);
    delete clients[id];
  });

});
```

What I really like here is

1. Event-based approach allows me to send data to clients whenever I want to
2. All clients are stored in a simple `clients` dictionary. I can access it easily, no need of using some external server to exchange data between clients.

To solve the first problem (non-blocking event-based approach) in uWSGI I wrote this code snippet:

```
import uwsgi
from threading import Thread


class WebSocket(Thread):
    def __init__(self, env):
        super().__init__()
        self.listeners = []
        self._env = env

    def run(self):
        self._working = True
        uwsgi.websocket_handshake(
            self._env['HTTP_SEC_WEBSOCKET_KEY'], self._env.get('HTTP_ORIGIN', ''))

        while self._working:
            msg = uwsgi.websocket_recv()
            for listener in self.listeners:
                listener(msg)

    def send(self, msg):
        uwsgi.websocket_send(msg)

    def close(self):
        self._working = False
```

So my first question is whether or not this will work.

The second question is how I exchange data between request handlers. I feel like I completely misunderstand uWSGI design.
I use `uwsgi --http :80 --wsgi-file=main.py --master --static-map /st=web-static` to test my application. Ideally I would just define an object in `main.py` and work with it, but I assume that this `main.py` will be initialized multiple times in different workers/threads/process.

I've already seen a similar question on data exchanging: [Communication between workers in uwsgi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16304343/communication-between-workers-in-uwsgi)

The answer was

> Pay attention, it will works only if you have a single worker/process. Another common approach is using the uWSGI caching framework (the name is misleading, infact is a shared dictionary). It will allows you to share data between workers and threads.

I see this uWSGI caching framework as some kind of independent external data storage (see Redis example above). But after I saw that neat implementation on Node.js I don't want to use no caching frameworks but just share the same python object across all request handlers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should invest in learning the sync vs async programming paradigms. The node approach seems easier, but only because you have a single process to manage. If you need to scale (to multiple machines or simple multiple processes) you are back to the "python problems". Having an external channel (like redis) is a common pattern, you should use it as it will allow you to scale easily.

Regarding python, uWSGI and websockets i strongly susgest you to look at gevent. The uWSGI websockets system supports it and there are lot of examples out there. You will be able to increase concurrency without needing to rely on callback based programming.

Eventually (but only if you like callbacks) you can give a look at tornado.